# Girdview is not being displayed in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

here is my gridview code

```
<asp:GridView ID="usersgrid" BackColor="Red" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
     <Columns >
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="Name"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Occupation" HeaderText="Occupation"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Education" HeaderText="Education"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Number" HeaderText="Number"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"/>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

in code behind I have done this

```
  UserProfileModel pr = new UserProfileModel();
  DataSet ds = UserProfileModel.Select();
  usersgrid.DataSource = ds;
  usersgrid.DataBind();
```

In visual studio Design view GridView is showing properly. But when I run the page in browser there is no Gridview showing. What happened with this code?

Comment: Your `DataSet` is probably empty that you're binding to. Please update the question with the code for `UserProfileModel.Select();`. To verify, you can always set the EmptyDataText property on the GridView so that if there are no results it's immediately obvious.

Comment: DataSet is not empty. UserProfileModel is Model and thorugh Select() I am fetching data from SQL

Comment: As I said, please provide the code for `UserProfileModel.Select();`. And let us know the structure and contents of the DataSet.

Comment: try to bind datatable of dataset like ds.Tables[0]...You can bind Gridview with datatable

Answer (score 0):

As at test can you response.write the data to see if is there?